# predict() method for "mice" package

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I want to create imputation strategy using `mice` function from `mice` package. The problem is I can't seems to find any `predict` methods (or it's cousins) for new data in this package.

I want to do something like this:

```r
require(mice)
data(boys)

train_boys <- boys[1:400,]
test_boys <- boys[401:nrow(boys),]

mice_object <- mice(train_boys)
train_complete_boys <- complete(train_boys)

# Here comes a hypothetical method
test_complete_boys <- predict(mice_object, test_boys)
```

I would like to find some approach that would emulate the code above.
Now, it's totally possible to do separate `mice` operations on *train* and *test* datasets separately, but it seems like from logical point of view that would be incorrect - all the information you have is in the *train* dataset. Observations from *test* dataset shouldn't provide information for each other. That's especially true when dealing with data when observations can be ordered by time of appearance.

One possible approach is to add rows from *test* dataset to *train* dataset iteratively, running imputation every time. However this seems very inelegant.

**So here is the question:**

Is there a method for the `mice` package  that would be similar to the general `predict` method? If not, what are the possible workarounds?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you get the answer to this question?

Comment: No, not yet) I guess another year might help.

Comment: The answer to this question is sought by many!

Comment: Add an issue here: https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/issues

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be logically incorrect to "predict" missing values with another imputed dataset, since MICE algorithm is building models iteratively to estimate the missing values by the observed values in your given dataset.

In other words, when you do `mice_object <- mice(train_boys)`, *the algorithm estimates and imputes the NAs by the relationships between variables in `train_boys`*. However, such estimation cannot be applied to `test_boy` because the relationships between variables in `test_boy` may differ from those in `train_boy`. Also, the amount of observed information is different between these two datasets.

If you believe the relationships between variables are homogeneous across `train_boys` and `test_boys`, how about doing NA imputation *before* splitting the dataset? i.e.:

```
mice_object <- mice(boys)
complete_boys <- compete(mice_object)
train_boys <- complete_boys[1:400,]
test_boys <- complete_boys[401:nrow(complete_boys),]
```

You can read [Multiple imputation by chained equations: What is it and how does it work?](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3074241/) if you need more information of MICE.